# Feign client is not working with @Patchmapping or PATCH method

Tags: spring-boot-3, openfeint

Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:489)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:598)
at feign.Client$Default.convertAndSend(Client.java:171)
at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:105)
at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerUtils.executeWithLoadBalancerLifecycleProcessing(LoadBalancerUtils.java:56)
at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.lambda$execute$2(RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:189)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225)
at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.execute(RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:136)
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:100)
... 183 more

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer which worked for me yesterday...

add the below dependency to pom or any build config

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and add the below bean method for initialisation of okhttp

@FeignClient(name = "<1feign name>", configuration = { FeignConfiguration.class })
public interface ProductService {

"FeignConfiguration" should be added in this configuration class
@Bean
public OkHttpClient client() {
return new OkHttpClient();
}